# SVG font not rendering in all browsers

Tags: svg, browser, fonts, font-family

I have an issue where SVG font is rendering incorrectly in windows based browsers.
Here is my code for the svg:

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> <svg
       width="34px" height="34px" viewBox="0 0 34 34" version="1.1"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
           <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.6.1 (26313) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
           <title>VS. + Oval 20</title>
           <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
           <defs></defs>
           <g id="EVENTS" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
               <g id="Sports-Event-PRE" transform="translate(-368.000000, -661.000000)">
                   <g id="Group" transform="translate(120.000000, 634.000000)">
                       <g id="VS.-+-Oval-20" transform="translate(249.000000, 28.000000)">
                           <g id="Group-9">
                               <g id="Group-10">
                                   <circle id="Oval-20" stroke="#4B4954" stroke-width="2" fill="#000000" cx="16" cy="16" r="16"></circle>
                                   <text id="VS" font-family="DIN-Bold, DIN" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" fill="#FFFBEE">
                                       <tspan x="9.468" y="21">VS</tspan>
                                   </text>
                               </g>
                           </g>
                       </g>
                   </g>
               </g>
           </g> </svg>
```

Comment: what does rendering incorrectly mean? Have you installed the font on some machine and not on others?

Comment: The site uses typekit to load <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/try3fbz.js"></script>

Comment: The font does not show up correctly on Windows browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and IE. but on mac it is fine.

Comment: Presumably because MacOS comes with that font and Windows doesn't

Comment: This issue is solved. I was specifying the wrong font. thank you.

Comment: do note that SVG fonts, as a technology, have been abandoned. We thought it would be useful, turns out actually supporting real world text requires an insane amount of markup much better transmitted in binary form, conforming to a format that allows for real language typesetting. That's why we now have WOFF, [universally supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=WOFF), whereas SVG support [has been retracted by almost every browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20font).